# How to fix the undefined data when fetching the response data from https request?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting the value 'undefined' concatenated to my original data when calling the HTTPS response data

This is for calling a URL and getting the response data
    ```javascript
    url = "xxxxxxxx"; //url is anonymous, so cant disclose

```
function externalApi(url){
    try{
      var https = require('https');
      var request = https.request(url, function (response) {
      var str;
      var statusCode;
      response.on('data', function (data) {
        str += data;
        statusCode = response.statusCode;
      });
      response.on('end', function () {
        console.log("Data is " +str);
        console.log("Status Code is " +statusCode);
      });
      request.on('error', function (e) {
        console.log('Problem with request: ' + e.message);
        console.log('Problem with request: ' + e);
      });
      request.end();
    } catch(err){
      console.log("the error is" + err);
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be {"MESSAGE":"No log found for ID 2"} but what i get is undefined{"MESSAGE":"No log found for ID 2"}

Comment: Where should your expected output happen? There is no `console.log` matching your described output.

Comment: Sorry. Missed that part. It shoud be Data is undefined{"MESSAGE":"No log found for ID 2"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `+=` with a string, you're concatenating values. [un]Fortunately javascript doesn't blow up when you concat an `undefined` variable, but it doesn't ignore it either.

In your case, you're *declaring* `var str` but you're not initializing it with a value before concat-ing onto it. If you initialize it with a value, ie: `var str = '':` it would no longer show `undefined` before the message.

IE:

```
// your code...
var request = https.request(url, function (response) {
    var str = ''; // this way it's not undefined
    var statusCode;
    response.on('data', function (data) {
        str += data;
        statusCode = response.statusCode;
    });
    // the rest of your code...
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Now it is working fine. But I have some different error. I give an URL that does some POST request. The url service stores data into the tables. But for this scenario I'm not able to retrieve the Status code. I get undefined as ouput. Below is the output i get 'Status Code is undefined'. How to resolve this?

Comment: @ArunElangovan Please don't ask questions in the comments if they don't belong to the answer/question. If you have another problem it would be better if you simply ask a new question. And don't forget to mark the answer that solved your issue as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating uninitialized variable with response `str += data;`.
You should initialize variable as empty string at the beginning.

```
var str = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
str += data;
```

to:

```
str = data;
```

Comment: That would remove the `undefined` only if the data event will be called more than once. And when the data event will be called multiple times received data will get lost, since you would simply override the previous `str`.